# Highlight errors in code in ng2-ace-editor

Tags: angular, angular6, ace-editor

I am using ng2-ace-editor in my project. I need to show an error or warning indication just before the line number where their is an error.

I am trying the way described here: https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor/commit/11a9c4025465190e2c8e35081e09e51fb32e7848#diff-aa2cbbf8c50873cb0bf8e42f52cf1319

```js
var Range = ace.require('ace/range').Range;

this.highlight.getEditor().session.addMarker(
  new Range(0, 0, 2, 1), "myMarker", "fullLine"
);
```

This didn't do anything in the editor. This is how the editor is called in the page.

```js
this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: editorOption.snippet,
  highlightActiveLine: editorOption.highlight,
  showLineNumbers: editorOption.line,
  enableSnippets: editorOption.snippet,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: editorOption.snippet,
  behavioursEnabled: editorOption.behaviours,
  wrapBehavioursEnabled: editorOption.wrapb,
  autoScrollEditorIntoView: editorOption.auto,
  wrap: editorOption.wrap,
  keyboardHandler: null,
  readOnly: editorOption.readonly
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Set annotations for ace editor from angular 6 can be called using -

```
 this.editor._editor.session.setAnnotations([{ 
             row: 1, 
             column: 0, 
             text: "Error Message", // Or the Json reply from the par
             type: "error" // also "warning" and "information" 
 }]);
```

Comment: A J
Thanks for the reply. This could help me to remove console errors. But, I could't see any changes in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

To show the error or warning symbol, you could use the setAnnotations:

```
this.editor._editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{
    row: 1,
    column: 0,
    text: "Error Message", // Or the Json reply from the parser 
    type: "error" // also "warning" and "information"
}]);
```

For getting the session you could use

```
var _session = _editor.getSession();
```

Comment: ```ERROR TypeError: this.editor.getSession is not a function``` this is the erro in the console.

Comment: Made changes to the code, please try getting the session using that approach

Comment: When I print the session in the console, I am getting something like this.
```
session:
EditSession
$annotations
:
Array(1)
0 :
column : 1
row : 1
text : "Error Message"
type : "warning" ```
But this doesn't reflect in HTML view

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by adding gutter information.

```
this.editor._editor.session.addGutterDecoration( elementPosition, "fa fa-fire text-info gutterMessages");
```

Thanks for your valuable time! :)